# Prefix all urls with virtual folder name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, virtual, directory

I'm trying to deploy my RoR 3.0 application on a server that is not supported by Passenger. Everything worked fine until I decided to use an Apache virtual folder for my application server. On the production environment I now have to manually add the folder name in front of all URL, for instance using a :host => "myServer/myApp" in all url_for calls. It works but it is painful. Does anybody know a nice way to automate it?

Here what I tried unsuccessfully so far after reading many posts:

- define default_url_for { :host => "myServer/myApp" } in application.rb, but had no effect
- I found some indication to define url_for and call super from inside it. No effect either

Thanks for your help

Hadrien

Comment: The two solutions you mention above sound like the best bet - if you can get them to work. You'll need to monkey patch url_for under ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper if you go that route. You could also try namespacing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty solution is to wrap everything inside a `scope` block in your config/routes.rb file:

```
scope 'myApp' do  # replace 'myApp' with the virtual folder name

  resources :users
  # ...

end
```